# WSL2 causing COM ports on Windows 11 to act weird

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, serial-port, windows-11

I'm experiencing some very, very weird things with my serial ports. I own a few tools that I use for various things, such as measuring the power of a device (using a tool called Power Profiler Kit II). I've experienced a few times, that the tool's software refuses to open the COM port. Like no error or anything.

I then rebooted my Windows 11 machine, opened the tool's software as the first thing, and it worked again. After measuring some data for a few minutes, I wanted to open WSL2 (Debian in this case), and I noticed the tool's software just crashed, and I also heard an "USB disconnected" sound. Weird.

So I rebooted again, did the exact same thing, and yep, I can replicate the same thing.

So it seems like WSL is doing something with my COM ports, which this tool's software does not like at all. I have not tried programming an Arduino or something like that, so unfortunately I don't know if it's a system-wide fault.

My question is then: Is there a way to disable WSL from accessing my serial ports? I don't care about those serial ports in my Linux environment, and if they're causing issues, I'd rather disable them completely in Linux.

EDIT:

```
C:\Windows\system32>usbipd wsl list
BUSID  DEVICE                                                        STATE
1-10   USB Input Device                                              Not attached
1-12   USB Input Device                                              Not attached
1-13   Logitech USB Input Device, USB Input Device                   Not attached
1-14   USB Input Device                                              Not attached
3-3    SteelSeries Apex Pro TKL, USB Input Device                    Not attached
3-4    Trust USB microphone, USB Input Device                        Not attached
4-1    Schiit Modi 3, USB Input Device                               Not attached
4-4    nRF Connect DFU Trigger, nRF Connect USB CDC ACM (COM3)       Not attached
```

```
ls /dev | grep ttyS3
ttyS3
```

Comment: From within an elevated command prompt run *usbipd wsl list* for us and edit your question to include the output. From within WSL run *ls /dev grep | ttyS3* for us

Comment: @Ramhound As you wish. I've added it now.